# How do I return a cookie from a jax-rs / rest-easy enabled method that returns a pojo

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I have to make a change to a javax-rs web app written by someone else. I am used to doing things the long winded way, and the javax-rs is new to me.The function currently looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("mypath1/mypath2")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public A myMethod(B myB, @Context final HttpServletResponse response)
{
    A myA = new A();
    ...
    return myA;
}
```

A is just a pojo, but I guess it is getting converted to JSON at some point in the process.

One thing I should add is that rest-easy framework is involved. I guess that is what's doing the pojo to JSON conversion.

I need to check for a cookie and take a certain action if it is found. I also want to return a cookie if the request did not have one. Reading of the cookie seems easy enough - just add this to the method signature:

```
@CookieParam("mycookiekey") String mycookieValue
```

My confusion is that the examples I see on the web show methods returning a Response, but this one returns a pojo - so how do I get the cookie into the response? I thought I could just do response.addCookie(...) [where response is the HttpServletResponse passed to the method] as I would do in my normal long-winded way, but I also see on the web that the way to return a cookie in javax-rs is a little different, so I thought I should maybe be doing something like this:

```
NewCookie newCookie = new NewCookie("mycookiekey", "mycookieValue");
ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(myA, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response r = builder.cookie(newCookie).build();
return r;
```

but that is returning a Response, and whatever invokes the method is clearly expecting an object of type A to be returned.

So I guess my question is, can I still return an object of type A from the method and yet have the cookie returned to the client?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK to return Response instead of actual entity, because the JSON it's converted to will be the same in both cases in the HTTP response, although in first case it is converted implicitly, while in 2nd you do it manually. So your snippet is correct, I believe.